# Hardware Dependent Encryption

Tags: disk-encryption

I am looking for a Linux based encryption system (like Truecrypt) that has the ability to do the following:

- Encrypt a partition or external drive that it can only be read from the same computer where it was encrypted. If the partition or external drive is brought to another computer it will not read the drive. Basically it depends on the hardware.
- If used on the same computer where it was encrypted it will load without asking for a password or anything else.

I have been reading the truecrypt manual but have not yet found an option or feature that shows me if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not do product recommendations here, but what you are looking for is software that stores the key in the TPM.  The TPM does not necessarily require a password for the key to be used, but the key cannot be moved along with the drive to another computer.

You should be able to use LUKS with the key stored in the TPM (there is a project for that called tpm-luks: https://github.com/shpedoikal/tpm-luks).

I don't think there is a turnkey solution for this; I would expect it to require some effort on your part.

Comment: Thank you Falcon. Between your idea and fr00tyl00p I will try to search from here on.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness. You can generate hardware dependent keys using *Physically Unclonable Functions (PUF)*. Wikipedia provides a good overview already. I would really like to see SRAM PUFs implemented under Linux. However, I think the most reasonable way to achieve this nowadays is a TPM as Falcon stated.